# How to calculate the supremum of the following function

Tags: real-analysis, functions, derivatives, convex-analysis, convex-geometry

Let me define it first
A $\Phi:\mathbb{R}\to \mathbb{R^+}$ be a convex function that satisfies the following properties
(1) $\Phi(-x)=\Phi(x)$
(2) $\Phi(0)=0$
(3) $\lim_{x\to\infty}\Phi(x)=+\infty$
the for each such function we have another associated convex function $\Psi:\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R^+}$ which is defined as $\Psi(y)=\sup\{x|y|-\Phi(x):x\geq0\}$ for all $y\in \mathbb{R}$ and satisfies the same above properties (1), (2), and (3).

My question: Let $\Phi(x)=|x|^p,p\geq1$ so we can see that it satisfies the property (1), (2), and (3) now I want to find $\Psi(y)$ for this so according to the definition we have 
$\Psi(y)=\sup\{x|y|-|x|^p,x\geq0\}$ for all $y\in \mathbb{R}$ , I am stuck here that how do I find the supremum of this function, what I know is to find the supremum of the function we differentiate it and equate it to zero then we find the second order derivative and check for values of $x$ but how do I differentiate here?

Comment: why if we have $p=1$ then $\Phi(x)=|x|$ then it is satisfying condition (2) ,right?

Comment: What if $\Phi(x) = \sqrt{|x|}$, seems like $\Psi(y)$ takes infinite values in such case.

Comment: disregard my first comment, I was thinking about $p-1$, I've deleted it already

Comment: My first answer was erroneous. Fixed it now

Answer (score 1):

Ok, since $x \geq 0$ we have $|x| = x$ and hence
$$
\sup\limits_{x\geq 0}\{x|y|-|x|^p\} = \sup\limits_{x\geq 0}\{x|y|-x^p\}.
$$
If $p>1$, the expression under the supremum decreases unboundedly if $x\to\infty$, hence the supremum is either attained at the left boundary, or at an extremum point. At the left boundary the expression is $0$, whereas to find extremum point you need to find zeros of the derivative wrt $x$. There is just one at $(|y|/p)^{\frac1{1-p}}$. Can you work out the rest?

Comment: I think in the last we will have $x|y|+xsup_{x\geq0}(-x^{p-1})$ you missed the $x$ right?

Comment: Missed the parentheses :)

Comment: $-1$ for "We can take $x$ out of the supremum". If $y = p = 2$, then the supremum is not obtained at $x = 0$, but at $x = 1$.

Comment: @Hetebrij you’re totally right, it does not even make sense. X is not a free variable here